# Fullpage.js - Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm trying to make a webpage that scrolls horizontally using [fullpage.js](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

I have the divs set-up and it works perfectly when I click the dot menu or use my keyboard to control it. Now I need it to work with scrolling.

So When I scroll down, I want to go to my 2nd div anchor point (just like it does when I press my right arrow key).

Is this possible in anyway? So far I only found [this example](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrollHorizontally.html#firstPage/1) but does that mean I have to pay incase I want this functionality or am I missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything :) You have to pay for the extensions.

Answer (score -2):

Just set:

```
scrollHorizontally: true
```

In your instantiate function.

You can find all the available properties for fullpage here:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs

Edit: updated answer. Misread question.

Comment: yes, that allows keyboard scrolling which already works. I want to be able to use the mousewheel to scroll to the next slide (horizontally)

Comment: Oops. Sorry - misread your question. There is an option for that too. I have updated my answer for you.